# Window buttons on cinnamon top panel

Tags: panel, window-buttons, cinnamon

Is it possible put the window buttons on the top panel of cinnamon like in Unity?

Comment: Cinnamon doesn't have a top panel. Please add a screenshot about what were you saying.

Comment: you can move the panel to top ;)

Comment: correct penreturn :), I like something similar to Unity panel (windows bottons on top panel)